# Reader's style sheet

Tags: css

In css while determining the Cascading of rules we / user agent considers one factor that is - Weight & Origin of the rule.

If we speak of Origin - there can be 3.

1) Auther's style sheet
2) Reader's style sheet
3) user agent's style sheet.

I know that
Auther's style sheet is specified in the HTML itself.
User Agent's style sheet is - the default setting's of any browser to render an HTML page.

But from where the Reader's style sheet is coming ?
is there any way one can load another style sheet in the browser & render the page again. Is that other style sheet called Reader's style sheet ?

If that is the case how one can load a separate style sheet for a loaded HTML ?

Please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: I think the second answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022344/css-newbie-questions-on-authors-style-readers-style-agents-style

Comment: Thanks,

But the question is - how a reader can load/apply his/her style sheet to already loaded page ?